# How can I make assets accessible to players for modding?

Tags: unity-game-engine

My game includes image files and json configuration files that I would like to make accessible in the deployed game's folder structure so that players can easily edit or swap them out.

I have considered/tried the following approaches:

1. My initial approach was to use the `Resources` folder and code
   such as `Resources.Load<TextAsset>("Rules.json")`. Of course,
   this did not work as the resources folder is compiled during builds.
2. I investigated the `Addressables` and `AssetBundle` features, but they do not seem aimed at solving this problem.
3. After asking around, I went for using .NET's own file methods, going
   for code like `File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + Rules.json)`. This seems like it will work, but such files are still not deployed automatically and would have to manually be copied over.
4. It seems that the `StreamingAssets` folder exists for this, since the manual advertises that its contents are copied verbatim on the target machine. I assume that its contents should be read as in the previous point, with non-Unity IO calls like `File.ReadAllText(Application.streamingAssetsPath + Rules.json)`?

So yeah, what is the 'canonical' approach for this? And with that approach, is it still possible to get the affected files as assets (e.g. something similar to `Resources.Load<Sprite>(path)`), or is it necessary to use .NET IO methods to read the files and then manually turn them into Unity objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking the same question on the Unity forums, I was advised to use the `StreamingAssets` folder and told that it is necessary to use .NET IO methods with it.

An example for how to load sprites as files using standard IO can be seen here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/generating-sprites-dynamically-from-png-or-jpeg-files-in-c.343735/

```
static public Sprite LoadSpriteFromFile(
            string filename, 
            float PixelsPerUnit = 100.0f,
            SpriteMeshType type = SpriteMeshType.FullRect)
    {
        // Load a PNG or JPG image from disk to a Texture2D, assign this texture to a new sprite and return its reference
        Texture2D SpriteTexture = LoadTexture(filename);
        Sprite NewSprite = Sprite.Create(
                SpriteTexture, 
                new Rect(0, 
                        0, 
                        SpriteTexture.width, 
                        SpriteTexture.height), 
                new Vector2(0, 0),
                PixelsPerUnit, 
                0,
                type);

        return NewSprite;
    }

    static private Texture2D LoadTexture(string FilePath)
    {
        // Load a PNG or JPG file from disk to a Texture2D
        // Returns null if load fails

        Texture2D Tex2D;
        byte[] FileData;

        if (File.Exists(FilePath))
        {
            FileData = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
            Tex2D = new Texture2D(2, 2);
            // If the image is blurrier than what you get with a manual Unity import, try tweaking these two lines:
            Tex2D.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
            Tex2d.filterMode = FilterMode.Bilinear;
            // Load the imagedata into the texture (size is set automatically)
            if (Tex2D.LoadImage(FileData))
            {
                return Tex2D;  // If data = readable -> return texture
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```